# Is there any possibility to use intersection types in predicates ? [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript, types, predicate

I'm trying to implement re-usable predicate type

```
type TypeLookup<T extends string>
    = T extends 'isType1' ? Type1
    : T extends 'isType2' ? Type2
    : T extends 'isType3' ? Type3
    : {};
```

So I can use it across these two methods

```
public check<T extends string>(type: T): this is TypeLookup<T>;
public checkSomeOf<T extends string>(...types: T[]): this is TypeLookup<T>;
```

So they can be used like

```
if (obj.check('isType1')) {
    // obj: Type1
}

if (obj.checkSomeOf('isType1', 'isType2')) {
    // obj: Type1 | Type2
}
```

I faced with problem trying to implement `checkEveryOf(...types)` which is expected to produce an intersection type between passed options, so

```
// expected
if (obj.checkEveryOf('isType1', 'isType2')) {
    // obj: Type1 & Type2
}
```

So my question is: maybe anybody could suggest something about implementing the last one ? Or at least in which direction to look at ? Or maybe will prove that it's not possible to implement that ?

As far as I understand in case of `checkSomeOf` method `T` can be simplified to `'isType1' | 'isType2'` so the result predicate looks like `: this is TypeLookup<'isType1'> | TypeLookup<'isType2'>`. I suppose for `checkEveryOf` predicate type should look like `: this is TypeLookup<'isType1'> & TypeLookup<'isType2'>`, but I didn't find any possibility to do that with array type at the moment.

**UPDATE**
Some checkable example

```
type TypeLookup<T extends string>
    = T extends 'isType1' ? Type1
    : T extends 'isType2' ? Type2
    : T extends 'isType3' ? Type3
    : {};

class Obj {
    public check<T extends string>(type: T): this is TypeLookup<T> {
        return !!type; // just some mock
    }

    public checkSomeOf<T extends string>(...types: T[]): this is TypeLookup<T> {
        return !!types; // just some mock
    }

    // failed to support predicate type for this method
    public checkEveryOf(...types: string[]): boolean {
        return !!types; // just some mock
    }
}

class Type1 extends Obj {}
class Type2 extends Obj {}
class Type3 extends Obj {}

function someFunction(obj: Obj): void {
    if (obj.check('isType1')) {
        console.log(obj); // obj: Type1
    }

    if (obj.checkSomeOf('isType1', 'isType2')) {
        console.log(obj); // obj: Type1 | Type2
    }

    if (obj.checkEveryOf('isType1', 'isType2')) {
        console.log(obj); // EXPECTED obj: Type1 & Type2
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZrXPm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz wow, I'm excited! that works exactly how I needed! thanks! yes write a answer pls

Comment: @jcalz ah, just caught one issue with it in child "is referenced directly or indirectly in its own base expression"

Comment: Could you show me that happening with a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?

Comment: in fact real project is a bit more complicated place, so I'm not sure how to reproduce it in this example :( Also just realized that the selected solution is not working at all, like the `check` will make `obj` as `never` type in at least one conditional branch whether it will be truthy or falsy in case passed string is not defined in TypeLookup. So I have to look at any another solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess I can't help you if you are unable to actually show me what's wrong with the proposed solution.  I can't realistically spend time trying to come up with another solution if I don't know what's wrong with the first one.  Maybe the problem you're seeing would occur no matter what solution is proposed.  If you do manage to produce a [mre] then I will look again.  Good luck!